# Причастие или отглагольное прилагательное?

Tags: причастия

Не все еще сказки рассказаны.
Почему слово "рассказаны" причастие, а не отглагольное прилагательное?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Прилагательное обозначает качественный (вневременной) признак, а причастие обозначает процессуальный признак (признак как результат произведенного действия). Например: крашеный - отглагольное прилагательное, покрашенный - причастие.

Мы считаем, что "рассказанный, покрашенный" - это причастия (рассказаны, покрашены - краткие формы причастий). В то же время следует учитывать, что
при отсутствии зависимых слов причастие подвергается частичной адъективизации, например: Я во все рассказанные мне легенды охотно поверил. - Рассказанные (устные) истории могут показаться вымышленными.

Но такую (неполную, временную) адъективизацию обычно не рассматривают, условно считая, что "рассказанный" и при отсутствии зависимых слов является причастием. В краткой же форме это только причастие (Н), в этом случае на первый план выдвигается процессуальнй признак, так как краткие формы чаще всего являются сказуемыми.

Answer (score 2):

*Не все ещё сказки рассказали.* Чувствуете действие?

Вот ещё примеры: *Девушка умна и воспитаННа.* Какова? – Краткое прилагательное, действия нет. *Девушка воспитаНа бабушкой.* Её воспитали, краткое причастие.